# Seamless Mosaic with "waved" Text - ISO Software

Tags: print-design

Edit: i asked my question [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/58045/seamless-mosaic-with-waved-text-iso-software)

I don't know if this is the right forum, but since it's "Art" I guess.

I want to make a nice background that is a seamless mosaic of "waved" text.
Do you know any software with which I can do this?

An example what I mean is attached:

[image]

Comment: Hi Alucard, unfortunately, your question is not on-topic here, as per the [guidelines](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might want to ask it [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graphic arts.

Comment: graphic design stack exchange may be a better choice for the question

Comment: ok, can be closed, i will post it there thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Adobe Illustrator is just three steps:

Create a path and apply a Zig Zag effect:

[image: Zig zag]

Expand this path and use the Type on a Path Tool to type the text:

[image: Type on a path]

Make a Pattern:

[image: pattern]

You can use this pattern to fill any shape type:

[image: Star]